# complete image is not coming when using feed post api of facebook

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, publish, facebook-page

I am using Facebook apis to publish post on my fb page.When I am uploading image to the fb page, image is not coming complete while it is cropped by fb when I see in console.

This is the code I am using

```
$data = [
                'message' => 'dummy msg',
                'link' => 'http://www.brainbubbling.com/',
                'source' => 'http://localhost/fb_puzzles/test.png', //(for with url)
                'published'=>true,      
                //"access_token" => $page->access_token                 
            ];

$fb->post('/'.$page->id.'/feed', $data, $page->access_token);
```

I am also attaching the screenshot of the image published on fb

[image]

I have tried different-2 images width and height as well but no luck. Please help

Answer (score 1):

You are not uploading a picture, you are sharing an URL with a picture. It should follow best practices and you cannot control how exactly it will be cropped for viewing by Facebook: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/best-practices#images

Better: Use correct Open Graph tags in the source of the shared URL instead.

If you want to upload a picture, use the [/photos](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/photos/#Creating) endpoint instead.

Comment: I dont want to use /photos because it does not allow to redirect on site by clicking on image.And in this api, I have to use the url where this image is put

Comment: then you have to follow the best practices in the docs. again, you are posting a link (with an open graph image), not uploading a picture. Be aware that the image can be cropped in a different way depending on the user device.